# I want to add data from AppInventor2 to a 68 column table and can't

Tags: list, google-fusion-tables, app-inventor

I am trying to make a rating app for pictures.  I have a list of 68 pictures that cycle through. I have a slider. I want the thumb position (rating) to be entered onto my Fusion spreadsheet for every picture. I have been chugging at this for 2 days and simply can't go on. Geniuses, what do you think?

Enclosed: Fusion tables screenshot, AI2 screenshot for one of my "ideas" (not a programmer)

[image]

[image]

Comment: This looks very cumbersome. I would rename all the images to be able to use just a counter variable. Doing this you do not need the 2 lists anymore. Also first do the [Pizza Party tutorial](http://explore.appinventor.mit.edu/ai2/pizzaparty) to learn how to work with fusiontables and see the [Top 5 tips how to learn App Inventor](https://puravidaapps.com/learn.php)

Comment: SUCCESS I did it! I kept the names, converted them to a csv list, invented a "dequotify" and "commify" procedure, and everything worked. cumbersome but effective. next time ill do it your way.